How to resolve "error: pathspec 'branchname' did not match any file(s) known to git" in an ADO yaml pipeline
We have an ADO yaml pipeline that will be triggered manually by selecting the branch at run time. The pipeline has a main yaml file that calls template files. However, this issue even occurs in a simple yaml file with all the code in it. Below is the simple yaml file (that can be used for reproducing) showing the branch is checked out, version info is updated to be added back (via the git add command), and finally the git commit and push are attempted. Showing these as separate steps because in the final version of the pipeline, we want them to be in separate template files with other tasks occurring in-between.
# Needed to avoid auto triggering on a check-in
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
    clean: true

  - script: |
      # Read package.json content into a variable
      package=$(jq -c . package.json)

      # Extract existing version from package.json
      currentVersion=$(echo "$package" | jq -r ".version")

      # Update version code by 1 in the package.json file
      package=$(echo "$package" | jq ".clientVersionCode += 1")

      # Write updated package.json content back to file
      echo "$package" | jq . > package.json

      # Bump version
      npm version patch --no-git-tag-version

      # Add bumped version info to staging
      git add package.json

      # Read updated package.json content into a variable
      package=$(jq -c . package.json)

      # Extract new version info from package.json
      newVersion=$(echo "$package" | jq -r ".version")
      newVersionCode=$(echo "$package" | jq -r ".clientVersionCode")

      # Set environment variables
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=OLD_VERSION]$currentVersion"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NEW_VERSION]$newVersion"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NEW_VERSION_CODE]$newVersionCode"
    displayName: 'Bump version and set variables in package.json'

  - script: |
      tag="new_version_$(NEW_VERSION)"
      echo "New tag $tag"
      echo "Listing current branch:"
      git branch
      echo "Checking out branch: $(Build.SourceBranchName)"
      git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
      echo "About to attempt to commit to branch: $(Build.SourceBranchName)"
      git commit -m "Update version from $(OLD_VERSION) to $(NEW_VERSION) [skip ci]"
      echo "Pushing to origin"
      git push origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)
      git push origin $tag
    displayName: 'Commit version info'

The checkout task appears to be working correctly based on the log file. Part of the log file is displayed below for reference.
Starting: Checkout mobile-app@users/userName/qa-test-pipeline to s
==============================================================================
Task         : Get sources
Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
Version      : 1.0.0
Author       : Microsoft
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
==============================================================================

< . . . >

git --config-env=http.extraheader=env_var_http.extraheader fetch --force --tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin --depth=1  +aefae8957f207e9285eeb81a9522a38134e1e242
remote: Azure Repos        
remote: 
remote: Found 0 objects to send. (0 ms)        
From https://dev.azure.com/companyName/clientProjectName/_git/mobile-app
* branch            aefae8957f207e9285eeb81a9522a38134e1e242 -> FETCH_HEAD
git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/origin/aefae8957f207e9285eeb81a9522a38134e1e242
HEAD is now at aefae89 Adding echo statement to test pipeline
git config http.https://companyName@dev.azure.com/companyName/clientProjectName/_git/mobile-app.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: placeholder_<guid>"
Finishing: Checkout mobile-app@users/userName/qa-test-pipeline to s

The errors / issues occur during the commit version info step. Below is the log file from this step for reference
Starting: Commit version info
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.246.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/runner/work/_temp/669d687d-3d4b-4e20-af98-ec9ca3c05cd7.sh
New tag new_version_2.99.8
Listing current branch:
* (HEAD detached at origin/aefae8957f207e9285eeb81a9522a38134e1e242)
Checking out branch: qa-test-pipeline
error: pathspec 'qa-test-pipeline' did not match any file(s) known to git
About to attempt to commit to branch: qa-test-pipeline
[detached HEAD 766da55] Update version from 2.99.7 to 2.99.8 [skip ci]
Committer: runner <runner@Mac-1734030477070.local>
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
Pushing to origin
error: src refspec qa-test-pipeline does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/companyName/clientProjectName/_git/mobile-app'
Everything up-to-date

Finishing: Commit version info

The [detached HEAD 766da55] is a different identifier than what was shown in the log for the checkout or even for the listing of the current branch in the above log file. The identifier in the checkout log matches the identifier in the listing of the current branch though.
Why is the checkout of the branch prior to commit the code (in the commit version info step) failing? How can this be resolved?
Checking out branch: qa-test-pipeline
error: pathspec 'qa-test-pipeline' did not match any file(s) known to git

Why is the push to origin not working? How can this be resolved?
Pushing to origin
error: src refspec qa-test-pipeline does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/companyName/clientProjectName/_git/mobile-app'

Is the issue caused by the detached HEAD issue and / or the HEAD identifiers being different?

Did you try to reproduce it in console? Please check what branches do you have just before git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName) moment. It looks like you trying to checkout the branch which newer existed in the repo on the agent
